# Map stored procedure results to entity in Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm having a bit of trouble mapping my search results queried via a stored procedure to my EF entities. I'm using a database first approach.

I can easily use `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>` to retrieve simple entities, this works and is no problem as long as my stored procedure returns the appropriate column names. My issue however is that I need to load related entities along with the search results.

This is what I'm working with :

```
// Product.cs
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
}

// Category.cs
public class Category {
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    ...
    more properties
}

// Brand.cs
public class Brand {
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    ...
    more properties
}
```

Everything works great when pulling data from the `DbSet<Product>`, navigation properties get lazy-loaded as expected.

Would there be a way to pull all the needed data from the stored procedure in a way that my related entities will be properly populated (ie. do I need to name my columns in some specific way)?

I've also experimented with a second approach, where I simply pull a `List<int>` of `ProductId` from the stored procedure and then make a second trip to the database using a Linq query to pull the entities.

```
List<int> results = unitOfWork.SqlQuery<int>(
    @"EXECUTE dbo.SomeStoredProcedure @Keyword",
    new SqlParameter("Keyword", keyword)
).ToList();

List<Product> products = unitOfWork.ProductRepository.Get(
    filter: q => results.Contains(q.ProductId)
).ToList();
```

Two issues arise with this approach : two trips to database and somewhere the ordering gets lost. First issue I can live with, this is a low traffic app and I'm not worried about the extra database trip.

Second one is a bigger problem though. The results get pulled in the right order in the initial query, based on some search value ranking in the stored procedure. That order then gets lost on the second query leaving me with a result set that appears randomly ordered and no way (that I can see) to order it back.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried importing the stored procedure as a function in your EDMX? You can set the return type and map the stored procedure columns to the return types properties

Comment: @James I have not. I'm using POCOs and do not have an .edmx file in my project. Could I just create the .edmx and only map the stored procedure?

Comment: You could, if you did that you would be as well to use it in place of your `DbContext` though as it does the same thing, with the added functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the .edmx mapping to work so I ended up sticking with my second approach and using a pretty hackish way to get my results ordered back the way they should be.

I pull my entities with two queries as mentioned in the original question (first list is in the right order) :

```
List<int> results = unitOfWork.SqlQuery<int>(
    @"EXECUTE dbo.SomeStoredProcedure @Keyword",
    new SqlParameter("Keyword", keyword)
).ToList();

List<Product> products = unitOfWork.ProductRepository.Get(
    filter: q => results.Contains(q.ProductId)
).ToList();
```

I pass both lists onto my view using a viewmodel :

```
public class SearchViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public SearchViewModel()
    {
        this.Results = new List<int>();
        this.Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public List<int> Results { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

And then at the view level instead of looping the `List<Product>`, I iterate through the results list.

```
<ul class="products medium">
    @foreach(int productId in Model.Results){
        var product = Model.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == productId);
        <li>
            ...
            display content
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Feels dirty and hackish but it'll have to do for now. Maybe I'll come back to it when I find a better solution that doesn't require using a .edmx file.

Comment: would you like to se how to do this using EDMX

Comment: @meda Sure, it'll come in handy when I run into a similar situation again.